# How is the following part working?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the following :

```
outer_dir=os.path.expanduser("/home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws")
print (outer_dir)
random_names = os.listdir(outer_dir)
print (random_names)
_____________________________________________________________
inner_dirs = [
    os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars")

    for name in random_names
]

print (inner_dirs)

inner_dirs = [name for name in inner_dirs if os.path.isdir(name)]
__________________________________________________________________
```

The part inside the box is what i want to understand clearly and also how its being executed. Can someone help?

Comment: The [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **[list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**, Python syntax elements that allow you to generate list content dynamically inside the *generator expressions*.

Basically, when unrolled, this code would look like this:

```
inner_dirs = []
for name in random_names:
    element = os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars")
    inner_dirs.append(element)

print(inner_dirs)

new_inner_dirs = []
for name in inner_dirs:
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        new_inner_dirs.append(name)

inner_dirs = new_inner_dirs
```

This is obviously not optimal (involves creation of unneeded lists and appending, so costs more time and memory) so such comprehensions allow you to make your loops clearer, more concise and efficient.

The evaluation order is as follows:

```
[(3) for i in (1) if (2)]
```

`(1)` gets evaluated only once on enter, `(2)` and `(3)` get evaluated on each iteration independently
`(1)` should be an iterable object, `(2)` should return a value that can be converted to type `bool`

Comment: beautiful , i am a beginner and wanna understand python better can u give me some more links to start python learning

Comment: @Kittystone if you're good with reading technical literature, [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) is a good place to dive right in. If not, consider reading some books on Python for beginners or taking online courses - there are plenty of them

Comment: one more small thing , `this_file_values = [items.get(key) for key in wanted_keys`  , its also a list comprehension ?

Comment: @Kittystone yes, everything that follows this pattern: `[(3) for i in (1) if (2)]` (where the `if` part is optional and there can be more than one) is a list comprehension

Comment: @Leva7 note that there can only be *one* `if` (although it can have multiple conditions). Also - any valid syntax after the `if` will equate to a boolean - it's just whether that boolean makes sense.

Comment: @JonClements oh, sorry, I meant to say that there can be more that one `for`